# Significant difference in performance for model.fit() when using the same training dataset in validation data

Tags: python, computer-vision, tensorflow-datasets, tf.keras

I am currently working on a simple classification problem using a feature extractor and classifier. For the feature extractor, I am using the pretrained ResNet50 model found in tf.keras.application in **TF 1.15.2**. I am doing a 2 staged training where I train the feature extractor in the first stage (no issues here) and training the classifier in the second stage where I freeze the trained feature extractor (issues here). I am using a batch size of 128 and learning rate of 0.3 for training the classifier. I have faced issues with the performance of the actual validation set which is why I am checking the performance of the training set to better understand what is the issue with my code.

Here is my code to load the dataset

```
def make_generator(images, labels):
    def _generator():
        for image, label in zip(images, labels):
            yield image, np.array(label)
    return _generator

def create_dataset(dataset_dict, shuffle=False):
    images = []
    labels = []
    buffer_size = 0
    for k,v in dataset_dict.items():
        images += v
        labels += [k for _ in v]
        buffer_size += len(v)   
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(make_generator(images, labels),
              (tf.float32, tf.uint8), output_shapes=(tf.TensorShape([HEIGHT,WIDTH,DEPTH]), tf.TensorShape([])))
    if shuffle:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size, reshuffle_each_iteration=True)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True) \
                        .prefetch(10)

    return dataset
```

where dataset_dict is a dictionary that contains `{label: <preprocessed images from class>}`

```
train_dataset = create_dataset(base_train_dict, shuffle=True)
```

Create model

```
def get_feature_extractor(pretrained=True):
    if pretrained:
        weights = 'imagenet'
    feat_extractor = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(
            input_shape=(HEIGHT, WIDTH, DEPTH),
            include_top=False,
            layers=tf.keras.layers,
            pooling='avg',
            weights=weights)
    for layer in feat_extractor.layers[:25]:
        layer.trainable = False

    return feat_extractor

model_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(HEIGHT, WIDTH, DEPTH), name='input')
feat_extractor = get_feature_extractor()
.
.
.
# feat_extractor is trained in first stage
output = feat_extractor(model.inputs)
output = Dense(num_classes, 'softmax')(output)
model = tf.keras.Model(model.inputs, output)

# freeze layers before classification layer
for layer in model.layers[:-1]:
    layer.trainable = False
```

Define metrics

```
loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'

if optimizer == 'SGD':
    opt = SGD(lr=learning_rate, momentum=momentum, clipnorm=5)
else:
    opt = Adam(lr=learning_rate, decay=weight_decay, clipnorm=5)

def sparse_top_3_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return sparse_top_k_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, k=3)

metrics = ['sparse_categorical_accuracy', sparse_top_3_categorical_accuracy]

model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=opt, metrics=metrics)
```

```
def scheduler(epoch, restart=50):
    if epoch % restart == 0:
        return learning_rate
    else:
        return learning_rate * (0.999 ** (epoch % restart))

monitor = 'val_sparse_categorical_accuracy'
callbacks = []
callbacks.append(
    ModelCheckpoint('output/local_base_class.h5', monitor=monitor,
                    save_best_only=True,
                    mode='max'))
# callbacks.append(CustomTensorBoardCallback(log_dir=tensorboard_dir))
#     callbacks.append(ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='sparse_categorical_accuracy', patience=8, verbose=1))
callbacks.append(TerminateOnNaN())
callbacks.append(CSVLogger(f'classifier_base_{datetime.now()}.log'))
callbacks.append(LearningRateScheduler(scheduler))
```

```
epochs = 10
logging.info("Starting classifier training")
history = model.fit(train_dataset,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    validation_data=train_dataset,
                    callbacks=callbacks,
                    verbose=2)
```

I am facing the peculiar issue of obtaining drastically different results for my `model.fit()` call and I suspect it has to do with the BatchNormalization Layer found in the ResNet50.

```
Epoch 10/10
82/82 - 22s - loss: 5.5539 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.5319 - sparse_top_3_categorical_accuracy: 0.6624 - val_loss: 74.7229 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0033 - val_sparse_top_3_categorical_accuracy: 0.0109
```

I then did a evaluation

```
model.evaluate(train_dataset)
82/82 [==============================] - 10s 125ms/step - loss: 74.7229 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0033 - sparse_top_3_categorical_accuracy: 0.0109
```

So I attempted a fix by doing

```
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
dependencies = {
    'sparse_top_3_categorical_accuracy': sparse_top_3_categorical_accuracy
}
K.clear_session()
K.set_learning_phase(1)
model = load_model('tmp.h5', custom_objects=dependencies)
```

But I obtained the same result

```
model.evaluate(train_dataset)
82/82 [==============================] - 11s 135ms/step - loss: 74.7229 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0033 - sparse_top_3_categorical_accuracy: 0.0109
```

How do I fix this issue such that I am able to get almost the same level of performance for the `model.fit()` for the same dataset or the same performance for the `model.evaluate`?

Comment: The loss displayer in model.fit and model.evaluate are not computed in the same way, it is normal that they do not match, so I do not see a problem here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I understand that the `model.fit()` validation performance may not match the `model.evaluate()`. However, I am still confused about why there is such a large decrease in performance from the original `sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.5319` to the validation `val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0033` given that one might expect fluctuation but not to the extent of the 100x decrease in performance. If you could suggest other reasons other than the batch norm which I brought up or if you know a definite fix for this relating to batch norm, I'll really appreciate the help :)

Comment: The values of `sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.5319` to the validation `val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0033` are obtained from the same dataset in the `model.fit()`call

`history = model.fit(train_dataset,epochs=epochs,validation_data=train_dataset,callbacks=callbacks,verbose=2)`